# Error: No overload matches this call, Overload: 1 of 2

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Following is the code for how I am using the router in the App.tsx in my code

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
return(
    <LoadingContextProvider>
         <Router>
            <Route exact path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
            <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={ProductsYouMayLike} />
         </Router>
    </LoadingContextProvider>)
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps | Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.  
    Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps, context: any): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>'.
```

What does this error means and how to I solve it?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I did, but the issue remains

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` is installed and used? Please run `npm list react-router-dom` from the project's root directory and report back. Please also include ***all*** relevant code you are working with and have an issue using. I suspect these issue is with one of these routed components. Simply adding the `Switch` component won't fix any Typescript errors/issues you face.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add the switch element

```
<Router>    
   <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
        <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={ProductsYouMayLike} />
   </Switch>
</Router>
```